# How to get data based on current day name in a table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, unpivot, lateral-join

Here is the sample
[image: See Sample]

How to get this data based on day name from my table?

Comment: You can only do this with Dynamic SQL. Personally, this seems like you should be fixcing your design.

Answer (score 3):

You should really fix your design. Each doctor/day tuple should be stored as a separate *row* rather than in columns.

For your current data structure, I would recommend unpivoting, then filtering:

```
select t.doctorname, v.*
from mytable t
cross apply (values 
    ('Sunday', sunday)
    ('Monday', monday)
    ...
) v(dy, val)
where v.dy = datename(weekday, getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Larnu & GMB, you should consider fixing your design. For time being, you can also use Dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(max);

SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT DOCTOR_NAME FROM MY_TABLE 
                   WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(DATENAME(weekday, getdate())) + ' = 1';

EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table
(
Doctor_Name varchar(20),
Sunday bit, Monday bit, Tuesday bit, Wednesday bit, Thursday bit, Friday bit, Saturday bit
);

insert into @t values
('dr.Sunday', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
('dr.Monday', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
('dr.Tuesday', 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
('dr.Friday', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
('dr.Tuesday&Saturday', 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);

select *
from @t
where choose(datepart(weekday, dateadd(day, @@datefirst, getdate())), Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday) = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

The following query will help you to get result:

```
DECLARE @SqlQuery varchar(8000) 
DECLARE @DateVal DATE = GETDATE(), @DayName varchar(20)
SET @DayName = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @DateVal);
SET @SqlQuery ='SELECT DOCTORNAME FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE '+ @DayName +'= 1'
EXEC(@SqlQuery)
```